# Several symmetry formulas?

Tags: symmetry

I have lost the book of my math course one day before the test. I want to review several formulas, but I haven't found them anywhere online. The formulas I am looking for are:

- Symmetry of a line with respect to a point
- Symmetry of a line with respect to another line

Comment: So the first one is rotating the line about the point 180 degrees, and the second is reflecting the line through the other line?  Is this in 2d or 3d?

Comment: 2d only, have to clarify it up. Also reflect rather than rotate for the point.